# OpenCV stereo camera (Thermal & Color) problem

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

I have been trying to calibrate thermal and color images with Checkerboard using OpenCV. The cameras are fixed one over another, vertically.

I have used 18 pairs of images for the calibration (One pair of images with detected corners of [Checkerboard images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOslx.png)).

The calibration code that I am using is:

```
int board_w = 7;        //no. of corners
int board_h = 5;
Size board_sz = Size(board_w, board_h);
int board_n = board_w*board_h;

vector<vector<Point3f> > object_points;
vector<vector<Point2f> > imagePoints1, imagePoints2;    
vector<Point2f> corners1(board_n), corners2(board_n);   


vector<Point3f> obj;

for (int j=0; j<board_n; j++)
{
        obj.push_back(Point3f(j/board_w, j%board_w, 0.0f));
}

for (int i = 0; i<num_images;i++)
{
    //read image and its corners from a file

    drawChessboardCorners(gray1, board_sz, corners1, true);
    drawChessboardCorners(gray2, board_sz, corners2, true);

    imagePoints1.push_back(corners1);
    imagePoints2.push_back(corners2);
    object_points.push_back(obj);
}
Mat CM1 = Mat(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
Mat CM2 = Mat(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
Mat D1, D2;
Mat R, T, E, F;

//Calibrating
double rms_stereo = stereoCalibrate(object_points, imagePoints1, imagePoints2, CM1, D1, CM2, D2, img1.size(), R, T, E, F, CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST,cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5));

cout<<"RMS error: "<<rms_stereo<<endl;


//Rectifying 
Mat R1, R2, P1, P2, Q;
stereoRectify(CM1, D1, CM2, D2, img1.size(), R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q);

//Undistortion map
Mat map1x, map1y, map2x, map2y;
initUndistortRectifyMap(CM1, D1, R1, P1, img1.size(), CV_32FC1, map1x, map1y);
initUndistortRectifyMap(CM2, D2, R2, P2, img2.size(), CV_32FC1, map2x, map2y);

//undistorting on camera images
Mat imgU1, imgU2;
remap(img1, imgU1, map1x, map1y, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar());
remap(img2, imgU2, map2x, map2y, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar());

imshow("image1", imgU1);
imshow("image2", imgU2);
```

However, I am getting RMS error: 4.32566. I have tried to minimize the RMS error and/or improving calibration result by using other flags in steroeCalibrate but am out of luck.

Is there any feasible solution to resolve this stereo calibration problem?

Any suggestion/help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am not used to openCV anymore, but why does a RMS of 4.3 bother you? do you have a target? do you know that is a lot of error? I mean, there will be error in the end, is 4.3 too much?

Comment: Dear Ander, Thank you for your message. The output of remaping image pairs after calibration is worse. I assume that the problem is with the calibration function and usually, RMS error should be below zero but I might be wrong.
Besides, any suggestions will be highly useful to me.